# Can you change the default layer color codes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For some of my daily tasks, I work on white in a template with 6 default layers, and the default seventh color is a bright yellow that clashes hard with white, kind of impossible to focus on. Is it possible to either

A) remove yellow and other light colors from the queue of colors Illustrator uses for layers?
B) specify which colors I want it to cycle through?

Or do I just have to stick with the workaround - keep a yellow-coded layer inactive strictly so it will cycle to the next color (grey, which is also less than ideal)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about changing the default options that AI cycles through, but you *can* change the colors of the layers to whichever you'd like at any time.

Just double-click on the layer in the layers palette to bring up this window:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I know about this, just trying to eliminate that step.